# How to Populate ListView from a different namespace in a client server centric

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

This program is a client server program using Asynchronous Socket. I have the server side working very fine, the client side where i am having problem is receiving the data sent from the server side but the data is unable to be populated in the `ListView`, if I use message box to display the message it works fine but populating it to `ListView` becomes the problem.

**ReadCallBack**

This method is the Asynchronous method that receive data from server, it will then feed it's output to the second Method Called  from a different class.

```cs
private static void ReadCallBack(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    try
    {
        string content = String.Empty;
        objectState state = (objectState)ar.AsyncState;
        Socket handler = state.wsocket;
        int byteread = handler.EndReceive(ar);

        if (byteread > 0)
        {
            state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer, 0, byteread));
            content = state.sb.ToString();
            if (content.IndexOf("<EOF>", StringComparison.Ordinal) > 0)
            {
                userControls.UCInventoryHome uci = new userControls.UCInventoryHome();
                inventory inv = new inventory();
                inv.fetchitemAll(content, uci.listView1);
            }
            else
            {
                handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, objectState.bufferSize, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReadCallBack), state);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

**fetchitemAll**

Implements the population of the `ListView` while the last method is the event handler for the `ListView` residing in a different class and namespace.

```cs
public void fetchitemAll(string stream, ListView listv)
{
    string[] reader = stream.Split(',');
    try
    {
        if (stream.IndexOf("<EOF>", StringComparison.Ordinal) > 0)
        {
            ListViewItem lv = new ListViewItem();
            lv.Text = reader[0];
            lv.SubItems.Add(reader[1]);
            lv.SubItems.Add(reader[2]);
            lv.SubItems.Add(reader[3]);
            lv.SubItems.Add(reader[4]);
            lv.SubItems.Add(reader[5]);
            lv.SubItems.Add(reader[6]);
            lv.SubItems.Add(reader[7]);
            lv.SubItems.Add(reader[8]);
            lv.SubItems.Add(reader[9]);
            lv.SubItems.Add(reader[10]);
            lv.SubItems.Add(reader[11]);
            lv.SubItems.Add(reader[12]);
            lv.SubItems.Add(reader[13]);
            listv.Items.Add(lv);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

```cs
private void btnUCInventoryHomeViewAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    sv.sender("fetchItemReceiptNoCondition,N00n,N00n," + Environment.UserName + ",192.168.0.11," + publicva.port + ", <EOF>", "192.168.0.10", 4343);// this code sent instruction to the server to fetch an information
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In **fetchitemAll**, since `reader` is a list of strings, you can just add them to `listv` individually without creating a `ListViewItem`:

```cs
foreach (var item in reader)
{
    listv.Items.Add(item);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @fmcgarry, that's has improve my coding standard but it's yet to solve my primary problem on the post